# Escaping double quotes in JavaScript onClick event handler

Tags: javascript, html, escaping, dom-events

The simple code block below can be served up in a static HTML page but results in a JavaScript error.  How should you escape the embedded double quote in the `onClick` handler (i.e. "xyz)?  Note that the HTML is generated dynamically by pulling data from a database, the data of which is snippets of other HTML code that could have either single or double quotes.  It seems that adding a single backslash ahead of the double quote character doesn't do the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function parse(a, b, c) {
        alert(c);
    }
</script>

<a href="#x" onclick="parse('#', false, '<a href=\"xyz'); return false">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Did you try

**`&quot;`** or **`\x22`**

instead of

```
\"
```

?

Comment: I just tested this in FF3.6 and IE8 under a similar scenario and it didn't work. However replacing the " with &quot; did. I also tested the exact code above and it worked both ways. In short the \x22 does not appear to work under all scenarios and you should try &quot; in that event.

Comment: Nice. &quot; seems to work in html tag attributes in Webkit and Firefox and Opera.

Comment: For me, `&quot;` worked fine inside an click event: `<a href="javascript:;" onclick="$(&quot;[id$='_txtFieldToClear']&quot;).val(&quot;&quot;);">Clear</a>`

Answer (score 65):

It needs to be HTML-escaped, not Javascript-escaped. Change `\"` to **`&quot;`**

Comment: The better answer, since it also explains the "why"

Answer (score 8):

While I agree with CMS about doing this in an unobtrusive manner (via a lib like jquery or dojo), here's what also work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function parse(a, b, c) {
    alert(c);
  }

</script>

<a href="#x" onclick="parse('#', false, 'xyc&quot;foo');return false;">Test</a>
```

The reason it barfs is not because of JavaScript, it's because of the HTML parser.  It has no concept of escaped quotes to it trundles along looking for the end quote and finds it and returns that as the onclick function.  This is invalid javascript though so you don't find about the error until JavaScript tries to execute the function..

Comment: Downvote. You do NOT need a framework for something like this!

Answer (score 5):

You may also want to try two backslashes `(\\")` to escape the escape character.

Comment: Classic. Stackoverflow ate one of your backslashes and displayed only the other one. I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best approach is to assign the onclick handler [unobtrusively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Something like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var myLink = document.getElementsById('myLinkId');
    myLink.onclick = function(){ 
        parse('#', false, '<a href="xyz');
        return false;
    }
}

//...


<a href="#" id="myLink">Test</a>
```