# Escape Characters in JavaScript Function for Double quote

Tags: javascript

I have a web application where I am dynamically creating a url.  The url has a parameter and I must pass a double quote.  I have tried this all different ways but it is still not working.  Anybody have any ideas?

To create the URL:

```
searchSurveyDetail.setSurveyFormURL(surveyDetail.getSurveyFormURL()+"#search="+ "\"" + searchValue + "\"");
```

on the Page:

```
onClick="window.open('${surveyDetail.surveyInstructionsURL}')"
```

The result:

```
onClick="window.open('http://www.mytest.com/survey1.pdf#search="company"')"
```

Comment: It wouldn't fix your problem, but if it's a link, you might consider using `target="_blank"` and `href` rather than JavaScript and `onClick`.

Comment: Even if it's not currently a link, you can make it a link. Or if you don't need to be compatible all the way back to IE6, you can store the URL in any element in an arbitrary attribute like "data-url". Then bind a click handler that will deal with your click. onClick is considered icky-yucky these days.

Comment: well, I wanted it to be a button and another window to open when the user clicked the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you need to double escape the double quotes. So you need:

```
searchSurveyDetail.setSurveyFormURL(surveyDetail.getSurveyFormURL()+"#search="+ "\\\"" + searchValue + "\\\"");
```

which produces:

```
onClick="window.open('http://www.mytest.com/survey1.pdf#search=\"company\"')"
```

which will escape the quotes properly.

Couple of things to keep in mind:

- This doesn't take care of double quotes in the search term itself. Make sure you escape that.
- I'm not sure why you want to wrap the search term in double quotes. For a typical search url, you'll want a query string like: `search=term` not `search="term"` because you'll just end up stripping the quotes later. But maybe you need that for some reason.

Comment: Hi, yes I need the double quotes because when you search a pdf it needs the double quotes or else it open 2 docs?  What do you mean by escape he search term itself?  I get the resulting onClick as you put above but it still throws an error and will not execute the open command.  the error is :Unterminated String Constant

Comment: Can you give me the exact HTML that's produced?

Comment: <input type="button" class="small-short inner2" value="Form" alt="Select" title="Select" onClick="window.open('http://www.mytest.com/survey1.pdf#search=\"company\"')"/>

Comment: Looks like you can't escape double quotes that way, you have to use &quot;. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081573/escaping-double-quotes-in-javascript-onclick-event-handler and then this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VTApR/1/.

Comment: great thanks so much.  I had tried that before but it didn't work, but after reading the post that you listed I realized that I didn't need to include the semi-colon.  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I gather you're using PHP on the server side? In that case you should run the URL through `htmlspecialchars()` before concatenating it to the HTML.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for your reply.  I am not using PHP.  The application is a spring Java app.