# Using onclick even in linkbutton javascript call with leading zeros

Tags: asp.net

In my linkbutton I have the follwoing code that passed a value from the gridview to a javascript function

```
OnClientClick='<%# "msgDisp("+ Eval("LOOKUP_ID") + ");" %>'
```

When I view the page source is looks like this

```
onclick="msgDisp(01037460);"
```

Which casues me problem, because the leading 0 gets dropped when passed to the javascript function.

The page should display something like

```
onclick="msgDisp('01037460');"
```

with single quotes. But I cant format my OnClientClick to produce the single quotes without getting a malformed tag message

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Sorry I forgot to mention I need to add ;return false somehwere in there to prevent the postback

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081573/escaping-double-quotes-in-javascript-onclick-event-handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could escape the javascript quote, this should work:

```
OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("msgDisp(\"{0}\")", Eval("LOOKUP_ID")) %>'
```

or

```
OnClientClick='<%# "msgDisp(\"" + Eval("LOOKUP_ID" ) + "\");" %>'
```

Another approach i would use is to use codebehind. `RowDataBound` of the `GridView` is the best place.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I need to add ;return false somehwere in there to prevent the postback

Comment: @totalitarian: and why is that a problem?